# Linked Mac accounts

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, accounts

I have three different accounts on my MacBook Air. They are all for me, but I use them for different things (Personal, Work and Study) because it's a great way to stay organised, but I have a problem.They are all admin accounts. 
When I only had two accounts (Personal and Work) it worked great, but when I created the 3rd one it somehow became linked to my Work account. 
So now every time I create a file or a folder on my Work profile, it also appears in my Study profile. If I delete it from Study, it also disappears from Work. 
I tried looking online for a solution but I couldn't find any other person who had this problem and complained about it. 
Any ideas? 
Thanks, 
Ioana

Comment: What do you mean by profile?

Comment: Have you logged into iCloud using the same Apple ID in more than one accounts and have Documents & Desktop sharing turned on?